# Send a php variable to a different js page

Tags: javascript, php, var

I am facing a little js/php issue. I have 2 different files (a .php one and a .js one containing some scripts the .php page will execute). I would like to send a php variable to the .js page. I looked over the internet but did not find anything that could help me...
Thanks for your help !

Comment: need more info. Where and how is the JS executed? When do you need to send the variable?

Comment: What is a *.js page*? Is this an HTML document generated from Node.js or something?

Comment: A js page is a Javscript page. The script is executed when the user clicks on a link (in the .php page). At this very moment, i need to send the .js page the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to define a JS variable in the HTML (produced by your PHP script):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var SOME_VAR = <?= json_encode($myvariable) ?>;
</script>
```

I'm using `json_encode()`, since it will add quotes around strings, and write arrays etc so that it's valid JavaScript.

**After** that, link the external JS file, in which you can use `SOME_VAR` with the value that came from PHP.

Comment: i deleted my answer .. stackoverflow is too fast :) .. also one upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can't send php variable directly to js file. For this purpose you have to write php value in a hidden or text field then get that value in js.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to embed the php variable in an hidden input field and try to access that input field in javascript.

```
 <input type = "hidden" id = "phpvar" value <?php echo $hiddenVar; ?> />
  in javascript 
 var hiddenPhpVar = document.getElementById('phpvar').value;
```

Comment: input outside form is not valid, if I'm not mistaken.